# problema al buscar en una lista c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

tengo una lista de libros y quiero buscar uno pero a la hora de hacerlo no me lo esta devolviendo.

Instancia de la lista:

```
public class Biblioteca
{
    public List<Libro> LaListaDeLibros { get; set; }

    public Biblioteca()
    {
        LaListaDeLibros = new List<Libro>();
    }

    public void AgregarLibro(Libro nuevoLibro)
    {
        LaListaDeLibros.Add(nuevoLibro);
    }
```

mi metodo obtener:

```
  public Libro ObtenerUnLibro(string NombreDelLibro)
    {
        Libro elLibroBuscado = new Libro();
        foreach (Libro elLibro in LaListaDeLibros)
        {
            if (elLibro.Nombre.Equals(NombreDelLibro))
            {
                elLibroBuscado = elLibro;
                return elLibroBuscado;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

mi evento del boton:

```
private void btnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LogicaDeNegocio.Biblioteca ElGetorDeLibros = new LogicaDeNegocio.Biblioteca();
        if (ElGetorDeLibros.VerificarLaExistenciaDeUnLibro(txtNombreLibro.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Libro encontrado", "Encontrado", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            txtNombrePersona.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("El Libro no existe", "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
     }
```

metodo verificar:

```
public Boolean VerificarLaExistenciaDeUnLibro(string nombre)
{
   if (ObtenerUnLibro(nombre) == null)
   {
      return false;
   }
      return true;
   }
}
```

lo corri paso a paso y a la hora de que llega al foreach me sale la lista en 0, pero si esta agregando bien a la lista, entonces no se que podria ser el error.

Gracias!

Comment: Si en el foreach la lista está en ceros, entonces hay que revisar cómo estás inicializando la lista en la clase donde haces la búsqueda, de dónde sacas la información. Por favor incluye el código correspondiente

Comment: En el evento click estas creando un objeto biblioteca nuevo ¿La instancia se crea ya con libros dentro? ¿Que hay dentro de la funcion `VerificarLaExistenciaDeUnLibro` ?

Comment: asi inicializo la lista.  el metodo verificar solo llama al obtener y si ya tiene que tener los libros.

Comment: El codigo de obtenerunlibro no esta recibiendo la lista. ese codigo deberia estar dentro de la clase Biblioteca, o recibir un objeto biblioteca que pueda recorrer. No deberia crear una nueva lista de libros, ya que al crear una nueva esta está vacia. Deberias revisar conceptos de variables y sobre todo del ciclo de vida de las mismas. que dos variables se llamen igual en distintos ambitos no quiere decir que sean las mismas

Comment: @gbianchi el codigo esta denro de Biblioteca. entonces la lista no deberia inicializarce en el constructor?

Comment: Esta bien, Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toda la logica de lo que estas mostrando, es confusa y tienes conceptos erroneos.

Tenes una clase biblioteca, lo cual esta perfecto.

Esa clase tiene una lista de libros, lo cual esta perfecto. La lista, se inicializa (en cero) durante la creación del objeto. Todo eso esta excelente.

Ahora, es cuando empiezan tus problemas.

```
private void btnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LogicaDeNegocio.Biblioteca ElGetorDeLibros = new LogicaDeNegocio.Biblioteca();
```

Si hacemos eso ahi, estamos creando una nueva instancia de nuestra biblioteca. No suena logico, si estamos buscando, deberiamos estar en la misma instancia que seguro creamos en otro lado y tiene ya la libreria cargada de libros. Esta que estas creando aca, esta totalmente vacia.

```
public Boolean VerificarLaExistenciaDeUnLibro(string nombre)
```

Este metodo, no tiene ningun sentido. no hace nada importante, salvo transformar un null en un booleano, cosa que se puede hacer en el codigo principal.

Algunas cosas que estas haciendo se pueden resolver con LINQ.

Fijate de entrar al objeto libreria que corresponde. No se el resto de tu codigo, pero puede ser, que directamente no tengas un acceso global a la biblioteca (casi que apuesto que para agregar estas haciendo un new de biblioteca y ahi agregas). Con lo cual agregar anda, pero nunca estas guardando la biblioteca entera!

Comment: Gracias! Tienes razón el problema era que la biblioteca estaba vacía por crear la nueva instancia.